# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una sentencia LINQ y utiliza una función estática en la sección `where`. La clase estática se llama `Funciones` pero siempre regresa un error cuando la ejecuto, la descripción del error es:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal FuncionMonedaMonto(System.Decimal, System.DateTime, Int32, Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

¿Cómo puedo ejecutar esta función dentro de LINQ?

Código:

```
var Query = (from TblInvCreditos in dbo.INVCREDITOS
                         join TblMovimientos in dbo.MOVIMIENTOS on TblInvCreditos.ID_CREDITO equals TblMovimientos.ID_CREDITO
                         where TblInvCreditos.ID_PERSONA == entidad.ID_PERSONA &&
                         !LstConvenio.Contains(TblInvCreditos.ID_CONVENIO) &&
                         TblInvCreditos.ACCESORIO == 0 &&
                         !LstIdStsSrc.Contains(TblInvCreditos.ID_STSCRD) &&
                         (Funciones.FuncionMonedaMonto(TblInvCreditos.I_CAPITAL + TblInvCreditos.I_INTERES + TblInvCreditos.I_SEGURO + TblInvCreditos.I_MORATORIO + TblInvCreditos.I_EROGA + ((decimal)(TblInvCreditos.I_MANTO.HasValue ? TblInvCreditos.I_MANTO.Value : 0)), TblInvCreditos.FCHFNLPROCESO.Value, (int)TblInvCreditos.ID_MONEDA, TblInvCreditos.ID_ZONA[0]) == 0)
                         select new
                         {
                             ID_CREDITO = TblInvCreditos.ID_CREDITO,
                             FCH_CREDIT = TblInvCreditos.FCH_CREDIT,
                             ACMSAR = TblInvCreditos.ACMSAR,
                             APL40 = TblMovimientos.ID_TRANSAC == 20 ? TblMovimientos.MONTO : 0,
                             APL60 = TblMovimientos.ID_TRANSAC == 20 ? TblMovimientos.MONTO : 0,
                             APL100 = TblMovimientos.ID_TRANSAC == 20 ? TblMovimientos.MONTO : 0
                         }
                         ).GroupBy(x => new { x.ID_CREDITO, x.FCH_CREDIT, x.ACMSAR }
                         ).Select(g =>
                               new {
                                   ID_CREDITO = g.Key.ID_CREDITO,
                                   FCH_CREDIT = g.Key.FCH_CREDIT,
                                   ACMSAR = g.Key.ACMSAR,
                                   APL40 = g.Sum(x => Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(x.APL40.Value), 2)),
                                   APL60 = g.Sum(x => Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(x.APL60.Value), 2)),
                                   APL100 = g.Sum(x => Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(x.APL100.Value), 2))
                               }
                         ).ToList();
```

Comment: El que sea estático no te asegura que sea alcanzable desde cualquier sección de código. Me parece que el tema va por el lado de usar un `namespace` en la clase donde está el código del método `Funciones` y en la clase donde tienes tu consulta de Linq hacer la referencia por medio del `using` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estás usando solo `Linq`, estás usando `Entity Framework`.

Normalmente linq ejecuta las funciones y procesa la información, sin embargo cuando EF está de por medio, toma el código y le hace un análisis estático para intentar reemplazar las funciones de C# por las propias de SQL.

Por ejemplo, en tu `ListConvenio.Contains`, sería muy pesado traerse todos los resultados para luego checarlos contra la lista en el contains, entonces antes de hacer la query convierte ese contains en un `WHERE IN ...`.

Entonces es fácil entender que cuando uno usa LINQ y EF, debe considerar que funciones se ponen en el where, por ejemplo, si quieres hacer algo con fechas te restringe usarlas así:

```
context.Tabla.Where(x => x.dateToCheck > DateTimeOffset.Today.AddHours(-1))
```

Esto marcaría un error pues EF no sabe como pasar ese DateTimeOffset a una función de SQL, sin embargo hacerlo así si funciona:

```
var dateInWhere = DateTimeOffset.Today.AddHours(-1);
context.Tabla.Where(x => x.dateToCheck > dateInWhere)
```

Esto es por que si save como poner un objeto DateTimeOffset, ya no es la función, es el valor en si.